# How to debug NonUniqueObjectException in Hibernate 3?

Tags: hibernate, exception

In our JSF application, we encounter from time to time Hibernate NonUniqueObjectException of the kind `org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session`. Most of the time, those errors are due to the following scenario:

1. Load an object from the database
2. Call business logic
3. Deep inside of the business logic, there is an hidden other call to the database that reload the same object.
4. Modify the original object and try to persist it
5. Get the exception.

Now since the app is very big it is often hard to figure out when the second call to database is done. Even when using sql traces, it happens that there may be several calls and I still have to find out the good one.

What would be nice would be to be able to call that method `checkUniqueness` that throws the exception from anywhere in the code but there don't seem to be any easy shortcut. Do anyone know a trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a look to Hibernate source code, I wrote the following class:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.engine.EntityKey;
import org.hibernate.event.EventSource;
import org.hibernate.persister.entity.EntityPersister;

/**
 * @author aldian
 *
 */
public class HibernateDebug {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateDebug.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public static String checkUniqueness(Object entity, Long id) {
        try {
            org.hibernate.classic.Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            if (currentSession instanceof EventSource) {
                EventSource eventSource = (EventSource) currentSession;
                eventSource.getPersistenceContext().unproxyAndReassociate(entity);
                EntityPersister persister = eventSource.getEntityPersister(entity.getClass().getName(), entity);

                EntityKey key = new EntityKey(id, persister, eventSource.getEntityMode());
                eventSource.getPersistenceContext().checkUniqueness(key, entity);
                return "OK";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
        return "NOT OK";
    }
}
```

Note that you must configure whatever initialize your app (for example spring) so that it injects the sessionFactory in the corresponding bean.

I am calling this method from the `Expressions` view from Eclipse: For example I am using a step by step progression with the evaluation of the expression

```
com.mycompany.hibernate.HibernateDebug.checkUniqueness(entity,entity.getId())
```

Most of the time it prints `OK` or the message about the object being already associated but no entry was found. But when it changes to the text of the `NonUniqueObjectException`, I know exactly where to dig to find out the culprit call to the database.

Hope this will help other people who struggle with old weird Hibernate exceptions..